# Unir inputs, segun el valor de una textarea

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas. Estoy realizando una function Javascript que toma el valor de una textarea y lo refleja en inputs. Si, no un input si no varios. El proposito de esta funcion es que cuando comience a escribir en la textarea, en el primer input comienza a aparecer el texto. Ahora una vez que la cadena de texto a abarcado el ancho del primer input, el texto continua en el segundo input y asi sucesivamente. Ejemplo, si en la textarea escribo "Hola me llamo juan perez y vivo en un pais", en el primer input si su ancho le permite mostrar solo "Hola me llamo juan perez y v" el segundo input debe mostrar "ivo en un pais". Mi codigo cumple esta condicion si escribes letra por letra el texto, pero **no funciona si pegas un texto**.

```js
function textarea(id,clas) {
    // body...
    r=[]
    var id_txt= id;
    var clase= clas;
    var b= document.getElementById(id_txt);
    var c= b.value;
    var f=document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[0]
    document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[2].innerHTML=c;
    var g=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[2].offsetWidth;
    var p=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].offsetWidth;
    for(i=0;i<b.value.length;i++){
        tx=""
        tx=c[i]
        console.log(tx)
    }
    if(g>p-5&&g<p+10){
        var t=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].value;
        r=[t.length];
         d= r[0]
        return d
        
    }
    if(g>p-5){
        var t=document.getElementsByClassName(clase)[0].value;
        
        return d
        
    }
    return undefined
}

document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("keyup",function(){
    aa()
})

function aa(){
    h=textarea("app","txt");
    var a=document.getElementById("app").value
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    if(h===undefined){
        p=a.length+1
    }else{
        p=h
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[0].value= a.substring(0,h);
    document.getElementsByClassName("txt")[1].value= a.substring(p);
    console.log(h)
}
```

```css
input{
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
  
  textarea{
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hi</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        input, textarea, div{
            color: white;
        }
        #gg{
            width: max-content;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-3">
            <textarea name="" id="app" cols="30" rows="10" class="bg-dark"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input type="text" class="txt mb-3 bg-dark">
            <input type="text" class="txt bg-dark">
            <div class="txt" id="gg">hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

La solucion que busco es:
1- Hacer que funcione la funcion cuando un usuario pega el texto.
2- Hacer que esta funcion pueda trabajar en un numero indefinidos de input. Actualmente funciona con dos input, pero como hago que funcione con tres inputs, cada input con diferentes tamaños.
3- Hacer el codigo mas efeciente.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para cuando uno pega el texto, tienes el evento onKeyDown
ahi actualizas una variable que diga pego por ej: a true

```
var paste = false
<textarea type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">

myFunction(e){
   paste = e.key === 'v'  && e.ctrlKey
}
```

El keydown se ejecuta antes de tu onchange de tu text area, Asi cuando llegue a tu onchange haces otro modo de update de tus inputs.

```
  <textarea type="text" onchange="myOnChange()">
     myOnChange(e){
         if(paste){
           //calcular el ancho del texto en un textarea
              //hacer un split.
          }else{
              //letra por letra
           }
       }
```